# Let $G$ be a finite group and $\varphi: G \to \varphi(G)$ be a group homomorphism. Prove that $\varphi$ is injective.

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

Here, we assume $\varphi(G)$ is the image of $G$ under the function $\varphi$. I proved that the converse is true of all groups $G$: i.e. if $\varphi: G \to \varphi(G)$ is injective, then $G \cong \varphi(G)$. The converse is only true for finite groups, which I am trying to understand.

Cayley's Theorem comes to mind, but we haven't gotten there yet. Clearly, there are many infinite groups for which this does not hold. For example, take $\mathbb R \times \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ defined as $(x,y) \to x + y$ is a surjective homomorphism but is clearly not injective, since $(3,4) \neq (4,3)$ but $7 = 7$.

Any thoughts on how to prove it is true for all finite groups? I thought about assuming $\varphi$ was not injective and deriving a contradiction, but didn't have much luck.

Comment: In fact, the converse has nothing to do with groups at all. What can you say about a surjective map between two finite sets of the same size?

Comment: I am a bit confused. Do you mean to say $\varphi$ is a group isomorphism? If you only make it a homomorphism, then clearly this is not true (pick the trivial homomorphism sending everything to the identity, that is pretty much never injective).

Comment: Sorry, I misread. You are asking, if $G$ and $\varphi(G)$ have the same cardinality, then the group homomorphism $\varphi$ must be injective. As Noah Schweber pointed out above, for finite sets, this has nothing to do with groups. Namely, if you have two sets $S,T$ of the same finite cardinality, then any map $f:S \rightarrow T$ is injective iff surjective iff bijective.

Comment: @NoahSchweber The problem didn't specify that the surjective map was between two finite sets of the same size. However, I think you have a point because if two finite sets have a surjective map, that automatically implies injectivity.

Answer (score 3):

This is obviously false. Indeed, let $G$ be any nontrivial finite group, $\varphi$ be trivial homomorphism: i.e. $\varphi\equiv0$. But $\varphi: G \to \varphi(G)=\{0\}$ is not injective.

Comment: The OP seems to assume that $\varphi(G)$ and $G$ have the same cardinality. Then the statement becomes true (for finite groups).